# Greater readability with png() ggplot2?

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, pixel

I trying to make a series of graphs to visualize array data. The x-axis is the gene name and the y-axis is differential score, a measure of significance. I have two separate data sets for two tissue types.

First, I would like to visualize data within tissue types. My first challenge is the readability of the graph. There are a lot of gene names on the x-axis however when anyone zooms in on the graph, they get a pixilated image. Is this a limitation of using png() dev.off()? Is there a way to specify a higher resolution image?

The following simple code produces this graph:

Sample data:

```
 PROBE_ID SYMBOL CT.AVG_Signal CT.NARRAYS CT.ARRAY_STDEV CT.Detection.Pval CT.DiffScore KO.AVG_Signal
1 ILMN_1223317 Lgals3      434.8137          4       83.70733                 0            0      1935.535
2 ILMN_3049559    C4b     1577.4540          4      237.21950                 0            0      6974.214
  KO.NARRAYS KO.ARRAY_STDEV KO.Detection.Pval KO.DiffScore  SEARCH_KEY ILMN_GENE CHROMOSOME
1          4       223.9622                 0     333.2554 ILMN_222956    LGALS3         14
2          4       531.5039                 0     333.2554 ILMN_210539       C4B         17
                                                                                                      DEFINITION
1                                              Mus musculus lectin, galactose binding, soluble 3 (Lgals3), mRNA.
2 Mus musculus complement component 4B (Childo blood group) (C4b), mRNA. XM_921663 XM_921673 XM_921676 XM_921678
                SYNONYMS
1 L-34; Mac-2; GBP; gal3
2                 Ss; C4


png("BS.png", width=1500, height=800)
g<-ggplot(BS,aes(SYMBOL,KO.DiffScore))
BSplot<-g+geom_point()+theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,hjust=1,size=8))
print(BSplot)
dev.off()
```

[Gene Array for BS tissue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwwt3.png)

Comment: Have a look at `?png`, you can set the resolution in dpi with `res`. However, `ggsave` is usually recommended for ggplots - if you save to a PNG it's just a wrapper for `png`, but is nicely consistent between graphics devices. If you really want to be fancy with `ggsave` specify `type = "cairo-png"` and use the cairo-device package. That will make text look much better.

Comment: I should point out that in `png("BS.png", width=1500, height=800)` you are explicitly setting the resolution to 1500x800 pixels. When you ask "is there a way to specify a higher resolution image?" the answer is yes! `png("BS.png", width=1600, height=900)` is a little higher resolution, `png("BS.png", width=2*1500, height=2*800)` is four times the resolution...

Comment: Interesting, saving with ggsave and "cairo-png" changed the graphics; the font and data points are larger. Both using ggsave and increasing the resolution are helpful! thanks.